# Match a pattern only when NOT preceded or followed by another pattern

Tags: regex

I know the naive way would be to use `[^a]b[^c]` (for `b` not preceded by `a` and not followed by `c`), but I also want to match `b` when it is at the **beginning** or at the **end** of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What sort of regex are you using? If you can use Perl regex, you can use a negative lookbehind and negative lookahead:

```
(?<!a)b(?!c)
```

Otherwise the best you can do is typically:

```
([^a]|^)b([^c]|$)
```

i.e. the b is preceded by anything but a *or* the start of the line, and followed by anything but c *or* the end of the line.

Comment: I'm using `std::tr1::regex` from C++ in this project, but it was more like a general question about regex. Is the first method better than the second?

Comment: Yes, it is (for example because it scales: `(?<!abc)d(?!efg)` is not as easy to write using negated character classes). However, not all regex flavors fully support lookaround assertions, so you may be stuck with the workaround version.